# MVC posted model is null when certain value is included

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Consider the following Razor snippet:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model, new {@class="col-lg-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Model, new {@readonly="readonly", 
              tabindex="3", 
              @class="form-control focus-effect", 
              placeholder=Model.Model, 
              title=Model.Model })
    </div>
</div>
```

What's intriguing about this specific snippet is that as soon as I remove it, my model posts back just fine. But if I add it, the model returns as null. I have about 20 other properties that are displayed using the exact same snippet (bar having unique names and values for title and placeholder of course).

e.g.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DMSStockNo, new {@class="col-lg-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DMSStockNo, new {@readonly="readonly",
              tabindex="5", 
              @class="form-control focus-effect", 
              placeholder=Model.DMSStockNo, 
              title=Model.DMSStockNo })
    </div>
</div>
```

The Model in question:

```
public class VehicleDetailsModel
{    
    [DisplayName("Stock Number")]
    public string DMSStockNo { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Vehicle Model")]
    public string Model { get; set; }
//snip
}
```

Is it because I foolishly chose to call a property "Model"? As I said, if I omit Model.Model from my edit form and post back, everything els is posted and I get a VehicleDetailsModel object passed to the controller method, but if I include it, my VehicleDetailsModel itself is null.

Comment: I've never run into a name clash with "Model" but I suppose it's worth testing.  What happens if you rename the property to something like `VehicleModel`?

Comment: Just did and it works. Let this be a lesson then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add this as an answer for completeness and for future visitors...

It would appear that there may indeed be a name conflict with the word "Model" in this case.  I don't know the details of how the model binder in MVC is implemented, but it tries to infer a lot of information from what is essentially very little information... namely the key/value pairs it receives in a POST (or GET, etc.) request.  Perhaps the assumption was made for the sake of the implementation that the word "Model" will be used for a specific purpose.  It's *probably* documented somewhere, but I don't have a link handy.

In any event, changing the property to something like `VehicleModel` should do the trick in this case.